# ESP8266 SPIFFS file not found

Tags: esp8266

I have a simple HTML file that I have uploaded as sketch data using the ESP8266 sketch data upload tool in arduino IDE. The file is 7k in size.

In the set up, I refer to the following function to read the file:

```
String readTemplatefile(){
  String retval ="";
  File fr = SPIFFS.open("/templatecfg.htm", "r"); 

  if(!SPIFFS.exists("/templatecfg.htm")){

    Serial.println("Template file not available ");  
    }
    while (fr.available()){
        retval += char(fr.read());
      }

fr.close();
Serial.println("Template file = ");    
Serial.println(retval);
return retval;
}
```

I always get 'Template file not found'. I have

```
SPIFFS.begin();
```

at the beginning of the setup function

My board is an ESP8266EX. I have wondered if it the flash size settings in the IDE that could cause this not to be found. Can anyone offer any advice on this issue. I have tried lots of different combinations of Flash size and SPIFF sizes without any luck.

Thanks in advance to any help.

Comment: Is the file there?  Is the media formatted in the right format (FAT? rather than NTFS which Windows will default to)

Comment: Did you mount the filesystem with `SPIFFS.begin()`?  Have you tried opening the "/" directory and listing the files, so you can confirm what your sketch sees as the available files?

Comment: @CodeGorilla: SPIFFS, not SD ;)

Comment: run the included FS browser example sketch and see how it works. yes, your flash settings can affect SPIFFS, if they are wrong. make sure the IDE size (`ESP.getFlashChipSize()`) and the physical sizes (`ESP.getFlashChipRealSize()`) match up. google the esp lib functions for docs

Answer (score 1):

SPIFFS will always claim to successfully open a file that begins with a slash even if that file does not exist.  Remove the leading slash.

Answer (score -1):

@dandavis Yes, I had SPIFFS.begin() in my setup routine.

I ran a sample sketch and was able to see the a file on the device, so I routed round the code some more and found than an included library was ending SPIFFS after it had performed a file read. This was the issue. Thanks all for your consideration, but the code I had was fine, just the included library was mis-behaving.

Comment: what library? so we learn